# Insert if not exists trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger in MSSQL 2008 that insert only if not exists, but I'm stuck at the `IF NOT EXIST`, do not know how do I use.

This is my trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER
TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_t1] ON [dbo].[MATOCSITEM]
AFTER
INSERT
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO  MATOCS (IDORCAMENTO, IDMATSITUACAO, IDFILIAL, IDAGENTE, IDVENDEDOR, DTEMISSAO, DTENTSAI, IDMESA, CHK, IDPAGAMENTO)
SELECT IDORCAMENTO, IDMATSITUACAO, IDFILIAL, IDAGENTE, IDVENDEDOR, DTENTRADA, DTHORA, IDMESA, CHK, IDFILIAL
FROM MATOCSITEM
```

I have tried declare variable, but it won't work, because my column has multiple data.

Comment: I presume this is ms sql server but please tag the question with a database specific tag, not just sql

Comment: Also, if you intend to insert into the `MATOCS` table, then why is the trigger on `MATOCSITEM`?

Comment: I don't think there's any point in an "insert if not exist" trigger, because the way it would have to work is by looking up I the row exists already and NOT doing the insert (by raising an error) if it does exist.. but this is what sql server does anyway when you insert a record - it either inserts (if it doesn't exist) or it fails with an error (if it does exist) which is what you'd have to do to prevent the insert. If you're trying to prevent insert into table b if a record in table a doesn't exist, use a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
ALTER
TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_t1] ON [dbo].[MATOCSITEM]
AFTER
INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


INSERT INTO  MATOCS (IDORCAMENTO, IDMATSITUACAO, IDFILIAL, IDAGENTE, IDVENDEDOR, DTEMISSAO, DTENTSAI, IDMESA, CHK, IDPAGAMENTO)
SELECT IDORCAMENTO, IDMATSITUACAO, IDFILIAL, IDAGENTE, IDVENDEDOR, DTENTRADA, DTHORA, IDMESA, CHK, IDFILIAL
FROM INSERTED
WHERE [YOUR PRIMARY KEY] NOT IN (SELECT [YOUR KEY] FROM MATOCS )
--- here you must have some primary key in `MATOCSITEM` and its corresponding foreign key is maintained in 'MATOCS` 
END
```

If it is not sufficient then kindly share your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, another friend fixed for me.

the problem was how i was using declare

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_matoscitem] ON [dbo].[MATOCSITEM]
FOR
INSERT
AS
Set NoCount On
declare @id int;
set @id =    (SELECT IDORCAMENTO FROM INSERTED);

UPDATE MATOCSITEM 
SET MATOCSITEM.CHK='True'
WHERE 
MATOCSITEM.IDMATSITUACAO=1 



INSERT INTO  MATOCS (IDORCAMENTO, IDMATSITUACAO, IDMATTIPODOCUMENTO,IDEMPRESA,IDFILIAL,IDAGENTE,DTEMISSAO,DTENTSAI,IDPAGAMENTO) VALUES
( @id ,1,1,1,1,1,GEtdate(),GEtdate(),1);


GO
```

Comment: You should be aware that this will cause issues for you, if you ever insert more than 1 row at a time.  What value will@ID have in those circumstances. Your update will also only UPDATE all rows with IDMATSITUACAO=1 which is probably not what you intended. The approach in the answer from @DarkRob will

Comment: It's ok, that will work in my specifc case. Thanks!

Comment: As long as you can guarantee that nobody ever will run an insert with more than 1 row, including through SSMS.